# Connection Frontend App with BackEnd App (only Javascript)

Tags: node.js, express, browser, frontend, backend

I need connect backend with frontend.

My frontend was developed with JavaScript, HTML y CSS. (NO frameworks like React, Vue or Angular) 
My backend was developed with Node.js, Express.js, Mongoose.

I want to connect backend with frontend, in other words, assign the IP address backend to IP address frontend.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure i understand what you are trying to accomplish here, if the frontend is just JS, HTML and CSS, just have express serve those files and u're done.

Comment: Not sure either what you mean by "connecting"/"assigning IPs", but you may be looking for [sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to keep track of a client or maybe [sockets](https://socket.io/) to communicate in real time between both ends.

Comment: Yes, I search solutions like sockets.